# Set QFrame width to match QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyside2

I need to set a QFrame to properly match a QTableWidget's width.
I have tried setting different size policies but nothing I have done worked, so I ran out of ideas.

This is my code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QTableWidget

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.showMaximized()
        # Create a table
        table = QTableWidget(1, 3)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'])
        # Create a frame
        myFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        myFrame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored))
        myFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        # Create frame's layout
        frameLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        frameLayout.addWidget(table)
        myFrame.setLayout(frameLayout)
        # Create central widget
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # Create central widget's layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(myFrame)
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        # Set central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

P.S.: I know `centralWidget` isn't necessary here, but this code is just a portion of my whole project so I have to keep it since the solution may be different without it.

Answer (score 0):

> sizeAdjustPolicy : SizeAdjustPolicy
>
> This property holds the policy describing how the size of the scroll area changes when the size of the viewport changes.
>
> The default policy is QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustIgnored. Changing this property might actually resize the scrollarea.

```
table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)  # <---
```

---

```
#from PySide2 import QtWidgets
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import QTableWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.showMaximized()
        
        # Create a table
        table = QTableWidget(1, 3)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Column A', 'Column B', 'Column C'])
        
        table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)  # <---
        
        # Create a frame
        myFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        myFrame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored))
        myFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        # Create frame's layout
        frameLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        frameLayout.addWidget(table)
        myFrame.setLayout(frameLayout)
        # Create central widget
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # Create central widget's layout
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(myFrame)
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        # Set central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]